"Many tries will turn failures Ƨ successes"
Find the next 4-letter word.


+---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+|   | |   | |   | |   | |   | | * | |   |+---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---++---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+|   | |   | |   | |   | |   | |   | |   |+---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---++---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+|   | |   | |   | |   | |   | |   | |   |+---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---++---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+|   | |   | |   | |   | |   | |   | |   |+---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+

Hint 1 can help in every step of this puzzle:

 "Many tries will turn failures Ƨ successes" - Quentin Lepoutre

Hint 2 (in the spirit of the title, I keep improving!):

 Find the next possible candidate that can be converted to a 4-letter word.


Hm I just noticed that the mobile-friendly version differs from the way the puzzle is intended to be (at least for me). Just saw it on laptop, makes a lot more sense now.

@Prim3numbah Yeah, apparently some but not all mobile browsers have problems with this box art, at least on this site. I will try to find another way to present it.

Aha I see what this puzzle is about now! Can’t find the answer yet!

The puzzle is hinting at

 a calendar, as seen by the first letters of each word in the title: MTWTFSS, which are the days of the week (starting with Monday).

 This is a month with 28 days, so it must be February (on a non-leap-year). The marked date is Saturday, February 6.

Hint 1 refers to

 the musician Myd, pointing to "month-year-day" format. The next one of these that can form a word is in the year 2106. On that day, the month would be 02, the year 2106, and the day 06; converting "02-21-06-06" to letters gives BUFF.


I realize it's implied in the first paragraph, but as a small clarification to readers: rot13(Fvapr Sroehnel 6gu, KKKK zhfg snyy ba n Fngheqnl naq gur ynfg gjb qvtvgf bs gur lrne zhfg or orgjrra 1-26, gur arkg lrne jvgu juvpu vg vf rira cbffvoyr gb sbez n jbeq jvgu N1M26 vf 2106. Fb gur fbyivat cebprff qvq abg vaibyir r.t. trggvat "OGLS" sebz 2/2025/6 (Guhefqnl) naq ercrngvat guvf cebprff sbe rirel lrne hagvy na npghny jbeq vf sbhaq. Orsber gur svefg uvag pynevsvrq gur sbezng, gur nfgrevfx jnf zrnag nf na nantenz vaqvpngbe.)

@LukasRotter is there any reason why rot13(gur F vf onpxjneqf)?

@oAlt rot13(Gur dhbgr vf zrnag gb or cnefrq nf "Znal gevrf jvyy ghea snvyherf 2 (gb) fhpprffrf". Fb gur onpxjneqf F vf obgu n 2 sbe gur dhbgr naq na F sbe gur uvag.)

Ah! I did look at that link from the moment the puzzle was posted but I hadn't pieced together what it meant.
